# All Section Edit on Shopify Are Global - Shopify Debut Theme Customization

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I tried following this guide to create an alternative template for customization.
https://shopify.dev/tutorials/customize-theme-create-alternate-templates

However, every single section edit I makee are global.

For example: I have two page template: pages.alternative1.liquid and pages.alternative2.liquid

Whenever I edit a section on a page with pages.alternative1.liquid, the same
edit affects the same section on pages.alternative2.liquid as well. Is this normal behavior from
Shopify? How should I edit the page then so that a change in one section
doesn't affect all template?

*Note: I am editing the Debut default theme 
using Shopify editor: Theme => Customize

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is a normal behavior.

**Static** sections ( they are the section that are called like so `{% section 'your section' %}` ) share content between them. This means that if you edit one anywhere it will update everywhere you use it.

On another hand section that are used on the homepage via the `{{content_for_index}}` tag are **dynamic** and you can create the same section with different content. (but only on the homepage or where the tag in question is present)

So if you like to have different content on the page a single section will not do you any good. You can create multiply sections with different names in order to use them on different pages, but if you have 5-10+ page it's not a viable option, since it will become too much of a cluster of section files.